# autocommand BufRead not working in vim when saving an empty buffer

Tags: linux, vim

I'm trying to use `autocmd` to get some filename-specific mappings. I followed some instructions online and write the following thing in my `vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile special.txt (some mappings here)
```

It works fine when I enter a file or create a new buffer with the name `special.txt`, but not when I create an empty buffer (for example, when starting vim with no argument) and save it with a name `special.txt`.

Even a simple `echomsg` won't work:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile special.txt echomsg test
```

and there's no text `test` in message history.

But in the documentation of `BufRead` I see

> Also triggered for the filetypedetect group
>   when executing ":filetype detect" and *when
>   writing an unnamed buffer in a way that the
>   buffer gets a name.*

When I save an empty buffer with the name `special.txt`, the buffer gets a name and `BufRead` should be triggered. But in fact it is not. Is there anything I'm missing, or I just have to use another autocommand event?

And in case it is useful, I'm using command line version of vim in the `vim-gtk` package from Ubuntu repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to interpret the help text like this:

> Also triggered [only] **for the filetypedetect** group when (executing ":filetype detect" [or] when writing an unnamed buffer in a way that the buffer gets a name).

So, this one works:

```
:autocmd filetypedetect BufRead,BufNewFile special.txt echomsg "ftdetect test"
```

Comment: It seems that `filetypedetect` is only used for file type detect commands, and I'm not adding a new file type. Should I put those mappings into `filetypedetect` group, or create a new file type for `special.txt` and write the mappings as filetype plugins?

Comment: If it's just a few tweaks and mappings, I wouldn't create a new filetype for that; use your judgement. For clarity, I would put those into `~/.vim/filetype.vim`, not `~/.vimrc`.